# Does Numpy allocate temporary arrays in expressions like x += 2 * y?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

When evaluating expressions like

```
x += 2 * y
```

does `Numpy` first allocate a new temporary array to hold `2*y`, add it to `x` and then delete it, or can it perform this whole operation in-place?

Comment: even more painful is the need of contiguous memory blocks for numpy array's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, that makes a temporary array.

If you find yourself needing to mitigate NumPy's love of giant scratch arrays, additional libraries like [Numexpr](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr) can help quite a bit, but make sure you're attributing performance problems to the right causes. Naive attempts to save allocations usually cause massive slowdowns instead of performance improvement.

Comment: numexpr is a fantastic library for working with large arrays.  I'm glad you mentioned it.